# How to verify TextInput value without using state in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation, textinput

I'm trying to implement a fast way of verifying and changing the value of a `TextInput` (it should only allow numeric values and a "." character) in my React Native app, but using states makes it very slow, as it being asynchronous lets unverified values be visible for too long before getting deleted.

I used a similar solution on the web recently, by listening to the `<input>` tag's `onInput` event and setting it's `target.value` property, but the update was instantaneous, with no unverified values visible and I would like to achieve the same result.

**Slow solution with state**

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const onValueChange = (newValue) => {
    const chars = newValue.split('');
    const newChars = chars.filter(char => !isNaN(char) || char === ".");
    const returnValue = newChars.join('');
    setValue(returnValue);
}
```

**The TextInput component**

```js
<TextInput
    style={styles.mark_input}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={newValue => onValueChange(newValue)}
/>
```

Is there a solution like using and changing an event's `target.value` property (like on the web) or anything faster than my current implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately the native input will update itself before react can even start a rerender. I've used two inputs to solve this problem in the past, an invisible one that the user actually types in to, and one that displays your formatted controlled value. You also have to send the selection position state from the invisible one to the display one.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `keyboardType` prop for `TetInput`. this prop might help you.
whe you set the `keyboardType` prop as `decimal-pad` then the keyboard allows only numbers and dots.
for example:

```
<TextInput
style={styles.mark_input}
value={value}
keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
onChangeText={newValue => onValueChange(newValue)}
/>
```

for more detail please check this [link](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/)